# loading sub-objects problem

Tags: django

I have an object `A` that has two `ForeignKey` relations to objects `B` and `C`, and a `ManyToMany` relationship to object `D`.

When I try to get an object of type `A`, say `a = A.objects.get(id=1)`, it only returns me the forign keys of the sub-objects and doesn't load them automatically.

In general I need to load all the sub-objects and serialize them to XML in my views.

Please your help.
Thanks.

Comment: you might want to edit this question for grammar, spelling and readability.  Using the Markdown editing features of the text entry will make your code snippets much easier to read, as would using hyphens in "many-to-many relationship"

Comment: could you provide some more information? What database backend do you use? What does your a = A.objects.get(id=1) code return? Maybe edit your question to post the exact code of your models (A, B, D)...? This would surely help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`select_related()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/models/querysets/#id4) will help with the ForeignKeys. There's nothing you can do about the ManyToMany relations though, you'll just have to iterate through in your view.